# Rails Tutorial - Chapter 12.2.3 Integration Test Failure - Expected True

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have been racking my brain on this for a while. I even copy and pasted the examples from the tutorial, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any help with this.

I passed all of my tests up to this point.

I created the integration test just [before listing 12.27](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-relationships_fixtures)

```
$ rails generate integration_test following
```

Here is my test/fixtures/relationships.yml file (I have been using mochi instead of michael the whole tutorial).

```
one:
  follower: mochi
  followed: lana

two:
  follower: mochi
  followed: mallory

three:
  follower: lana
  followed: mochi

four:
  follower: archer
  followed: mochi
```

Here is my test/integration/following_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class FollowingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:mochi)
    log_in_as(@user)
  end

  test "following page" do
    get following_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.following.empty?
    assert_match @user.following.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.following.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "followers page" do
    get followers_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.followers.empty?
    assert_match @user.followers.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.followers.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the test failure I am getting when I run bundle exec rake test

```
$ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 23507

# Running:

........................................................FF

Finished in 1.736838s, 33.3940 runs/s, 164.0913 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
FollowingTest#test_following_page [/app_path/test/integration/following_test.rb:12]:
Expected true to be nil or false


  2) Failure:
FollowingTest#test_followers_page [/app_path/test/integration/following_test.rb:21]:
Expected true to be nil or false

58 runs, 285 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what could be causing this failure, I would really appreciate it. This has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user.following.empty?
```

...is returning true. But you're expecting it to be nil or false.

> **assert_not** - Assert that an expression is not truthy. Passes if object is nil or false.

from [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions/assert_not).

In short, @user.following IS empty. Your test is expecting it **not** to be.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. If I comment out @user.following.empty?, then I pass the test. I will try to figure out why it isn't assigning followers to my user and report back if I figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have properly set your User fixtures. If you don't have users needed for the relationships fixtures, then it simply won't work.

Check Michael Hartl's GitHub User fixtures and see if you have them all:
https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/master/test/fixtures/users.yml

Worked for me.